# SourceTree wants to commit unaltered files

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am currently working on a php project I sync to a git repository from time to time. For putting it onto my repository, I am pulling it off the server which runs it via FTP onto my PC.

This worked fine so far, but now SourceTree wants to recommit all files, whether they have changed or not. This looks like the following for an untouched file:

[image]

Since I'm rather a novice when it comes to git, I have no idea where this comes from and how I can fix that. Since it does not show any change inside the file, I assume this could be connected to the file metadata.

Since my last sync, I updated my FileZilla and the server was switched from Windows to Debian. Could this cause some trouble here?

Comment: Since you switch your server from Windows to Linux, maybe line endings changed (CRLF to LF) take a look at the diff of the files

Comment: Run a `$ git diff` to see what has changed.

Comment: @ThomasStringer Running that only shows the changed files. DiffMerge does not show any difference on those files.

Answer (score 0):

I reset my current branch to the last commit, copied the new files into my local copy and now everything works fine. Could this have been a bug in SourceTree?

The encoding didn't changed, backups from the Windows server were also UTF-8, the same as the current files are.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on **unstaged file** and check **ignor** word and then **.idea** make changes. all files in future will go on **Stop Tracking**.

[image]